# Whats the formula for the amount to scale up an image during rotation to not see the edges

Tags: math, graphics, opengl-es

I've searched here and in google and maybe its that I'm not using the right combination of key words..

I'm trying to figure out how much a picture would have to be scaled up during a rotation (at each rotation amount) so that you don't see the edge of the picture in the square of the bounding box.

[image: Rotation Problem Graphic]

If the bounding box is square it might be a simpler formula.  But when the box is rectangle it seems like it gets harder to figure out.  The graphic above shows 30 degrees which took 170%.  I would think 45 degrees would be the worst case scenario.

EDIT: To clarify, I am looking for the scale factor to use given an angle a height and a width.  We can assume the size and aspect of the bounding box to be equal to the size and aspect of the photo.

If this should be moved to the math stack exchange I can do that.  Thanks.

Comment: You mean, the scaling factor given width, height and angle? Or a scaling factor that will work for any angle, given width and height?

Comment: Sorry.. I mean the scale factor given the angle height and width.  The input is angle height and width and the output is scale factor.

Comment: I did ask the question on Stack Exchange as well.  Here was that answer which I believe is the most correct.  I will look at your answers to see if ether of them are basically the same so I can checkmark one.  But the above answer is certainly correct.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438567/whats-the-formula-for-the-amount-to-scale-up-an-image-during-rotation-to-not-see/438573?noredirect=1#438573

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the picture has height h and width w, and the angle is between 0 and 90 degrees.

If w>h, the scaling factor is (w/h) sin(angle) + cos(angle).

If h>w, the scaling factor is (h/w) sin(angle) + cos(angle).

Comment: Yours is correct.  At least the if w>h part is.  The mathematics stack exchange answer only gave that one answer though.  Not the w<h version.  Do you think his answer is wrong if w<h?

Comment: @badweasel: Yes, I think that Omnomnomnom's answer assumes w>h, and is incorrect if w<h.

Comment: Yep, you're right.  I initially didn't bother to redraw the diagram and didn't consider what happens to the vertical edge of the scaled picture.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a scan of my answer :

[image]

Comment: Your theory is close but there is an easier way.  See the answer over at mathematics stack exchange:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438567/whats-the-formula-for-the-amount-to-scale-up-an-image-during-rotation-to-not-see/438573?noredirect=1#438573

He moved the line BE so that instead of it being BC+CE it's BD+DE.  Then you don't have to mess with the AC+CD part.  Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: @badweasel thanks for the link; you're right, derivation will be much simpler by drawing BE such as it passes through D.